# Are attributes allowed in a SAML authentication request?

Tags: saml

Is it possible to send attributes in a SAML authentication request?

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest
   xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
   xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
   ID="aaf23196-1773-2113-474a-fe114412ab72"
   Version="2.0"
   IssueInstant="2004-12-05T09:21:59Z"
   AssertionConsumerServiceIndex="0"
   AttributeConsumingServiceIndex="0">
   <saml:Issuer>https://sp.example.com/SAML2</saml:Issuer>
   <samlp:NameIDPolicy
     AllowCreate="true"
     Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"/>
 </samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically, yes, it is possible, since AuthnRequest can contain an Extensions element, which can contain anything - see [the SAML 'core' spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf): AuthnRequest (section 3.4.1) is derived from RequestAbstractType (section 3.2.1) which has an optional Extensions. The sender and recipient would have to agree on the syntax and semantics of data sent this way.

I can't see a more 'conventional' way to do this, since Attributes are usually in Assertions, rather than AuthnRequests.

Comment: Thanks for the help before.  I have a followup comment.  Is this for SAML 2.0 or SAML 1.0 or both?

Comment: That was for SAML 2.0. Looking at section 3.2.1 of the SAML 1.1 spec (http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/3406/oasis-sstc-saml-core-1.1.pdf), there's no Extensions element, so I don't think you can do this with SAML 1.x.

Comment: This post helped me greatly when I originally posted it.  I was able to use Extensions and Shibboleth to pass attributes in the AuthnRequest.  I am using OpenAM now and was wondering if it was possible to access the extensions from an AMLoginModule.  It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a case where attributes are to be part of auth request.
so that we can get that attribute name from request to construct response assertion with the same.

because service provider validates the response by comparing the attribute names.we can take the example of Salesforce as service provider, where the same happens.