# Causing IDP to include specified attribute in authentication response

Tags: saml

I've looked through the standard, as well as browsed the OpenSAML-J API, but can't find an obvious way to do this. Is it possible, and if so, how?

What I want is to include *something* in an `AuthnRequest` (which is generated by my code and posted to the IDP) that causes the final `AuthnResponse` to include a named attribute with a specific value. Ideally the attribute should always be included, but it will work too if the attribute is only included upon successful authentication. The desired name and value are both known when the AuthnRequest is being constructed.

I thought about `RelayState` for a moment, too, but that doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for either.

[Are attributes allowed in a SAML authentication request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529655/are-attributes-allowed-in-a-saml-authentication-request) talks about including attributes with the AuthnRequest, but insofar as I can tell, using Extensions to include an attribute does not guarantee that the same attribute will be included in the final response issued by the IDP. (But maybe I am misreading Core section 7.2.1 and it really applies to my case?) I can't rely on the behavior of a specific implementation; it must be guaranteed by the standard.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The only other solution I can think of is to store the relevant data locally and refer to it using the `ID` and `InResponseTo` attributes on the request and response, respectively, but that introduces a fair bit of overhead and complexity which I would rather avoid if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Could a possible workaround be to make an AttributeQuery back to the IdP after the user has authenticated?  In an AttributeQuery you can name whatever attributes you are interested in retrieving.  The response will return those if it can.

Not all SAML products support AttributeQuery, so I'm not sure how much flexibility you have on either side of your problem.

Comment: The problem is that the value of the attribute varies with the original authentication request, so the IDP would still need to store that information until it is requested, which sounds flimsy. Maybe I will have to bite the bullet and go with storing that data locally after all. At least `ID` and `InResponseTo` are both mandated by the standard, with semantics that would work for my purposes even though it means a few extra database roundtrips and some additional complexity.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend you leverage RelayState for this rather than ID / InResponseTo.  While I'm sure you could achieve the same thing with the ID, RelayState is intended to do exactly what you're describing - maintain state between request/response.  It could  contain some session identifier to lookup the attribute / values you're after.

Answer (score 0):

RelayState is the right feature to use. As all the values you want returned are already known during request construction time, you can just serialize them into a string, provide as RelayState when sending the AuthnRequest and get them returned together with the AuthnResponse.